# Running then method after XMLHttpRequest done

Tags: javascript, c#, xmlhttprequest

I have a method acting like an async method.  After the request sends to the function that was called this request, I want to run something like the then method but then there is no then method for XMLHttpRequest.
the caller function in below code has no then method

```
      let result = dataService.exportfile('get', '/api/overtimeedari/exporttoexcle/', model).
                then(() => {
                        self.loading(false);//غیرفعال کردن حالت لود  شدن گرید
                        buttonListSearch.Excel.loading(false); //غیرفعال کردن حالت لود شدن دکمه اکسل
                    });
```

the function called

```
        function exportfile(mehtodtype, url, model) {
            debugger;
            var qs = "?";
            model.map((item) => {
                qs = `${qs}${item.name}=${item.value}&`;
            });

            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.open(mehtodtype, url + qs, true);
            request.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "Bearer " + window.localStorage.getItem('token'));
            request.responseType = 'blob';
            request.onload = function (e) {
                if (this.status === 200) {
                    var blob = this.response;
                    if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
                        window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, fileName);
                    }
                    else {
                        var downloadLink = window.document.createElement('a');
                        var contentTypeHeader = request.getResponseHeader("Content-Type");
                        downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([blob], { type: contentTypeHeader }));
                        downloadLink.download = "Export.xls";
                        document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
                        downloadLink.click();
                        document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
                    }
                }
            };
            request.send();
            return request;
        }
```

Comment: XHMHttpRequest has no `.then` property - are you thinking of `fetch` perhaps? or something else that returns a Promise? a promise being the thing that has `.then` method - you could of course wrap the code inside `function exportfile` in a Promise if you definitely must use `XMLHttpRequest`

Comment: @Bravo I need somthing like callback function running after XMLHttpRequest is done.

Comment: sure, then do that - supply a callback function to `exportfile` and call that when required - that works too

Comment: @Bravo the case is I don't have this ability to change the` exportfile` function because it has side affects on other functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the constraint of not changing `exportfile` function as per comment

> the case is I don't have this ability to change the`exportfile` function because it has side affects on other functions

the best way to handle this is as follows

```
let req = dataService.exportfile('get', '/api/overtimeedari/exporttoexcle/', model);
req.addEventListener('loadend', () => {
  // do what's needed here
});
```

since `exportfile` returns the XMLHttpRequest object, you can listen for the `loadend` event and do whatever it you're doing there

Note, the `loadend` event is triggered regardless of success or failure

You could do the above with the `load` event if you want too - but, I'm unsure what order

```
x.onload=() => {};
x.addEventListener('load', () => {});
```

are fired ... also note, do NOT

```
req.onload=() => {};
```

since that would overwrite the onload callback inside the function